# Is there a keyboard eventlistener for android app

Tags: android, cordova, keyboard, cordova-plugins

I'm using apache cordova to develope my android app, and now I want to hide the statusbar when the keyboard is shown. Becouse everytime when the keyboard is shown, the statusbar comes up too. So I want to try this with an eventlistener which call statusbar.hide() when the keyboard is shown. Is this possible?

I installed the cordova-plugin-keyboard and added an listener to the onDeviceReady function.

```
    function onDeviceReady() {
    // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
    document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
    document.addEventListener( 'resume', onResume.bind( this ), false );

    document.addEventListener('native.keyboardshow', keyboardShowHandler);
};
```

and the keyboardShowHandler

```
    function keyboardShowHandler(e){
StatusBar.Hide();
```

}

But this is not working. Any Idea?

Comment: do you receive any errors ?

Comment: unfortunately no...

Comment: Are you sure that it jumps into keyboardShowHandler

Comment: no I think not that it jumps to this function. I see no log entry...